# Xamarin Forms - downloading images from Azure to local storage and using as image source

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a function that downloads and saves images from Azure to local storage in a folder called appImages.  I can then use the code below to open the image and set it as an image source.

Is it possible to save the images in the same place as they would be if included in the application, that is, in the android/resources/drawable folder, so that I can reference them as if they were there?

What I mean is, I can set an image source like this:

```
myImage.Source = "image01.png";
```

And the source is picked up from the resources folder.  Can I download and save to any location that would enable me to set the source as I have above, rather than what I'm doing in the code below?

```
IFolder folder = rootFolder ?? FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder2 = await folder.GetFolderAsync("appImages");
            ExistenceCheckResult folderexist = await folder2.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);
            IFile file = await folder2.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            using (System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
            {
                long length = stream.Length;
                byte[] streamBuffer = new byte[length];
                stream.Read(streamBuffer, 0, (int)length);
                return streamBuffer;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to save the images in the same place as they would be
>   if included in the application, that is, in the
>   android/resources/drawable folder, so that I can reference them as if
>   they were there?

No.

The application bundle is signed and read-only.  You can't modify it or write to it at run time.